# pandas to_timedelta function seems to convert data to 0

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

This has always worked for me, but starting a few days ago I'm getting bizarre results.

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_series = pd.Series(my_list)
print pd.to_timedelta(my_series)
```

which just returns

```
0    00:00:00:000000
1    00:00:00:000000
2    00:00:00:000000
3    00:00:00:000000
4    00:00:00:000000
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

EDIT: 
In my actual code I was changing my (soon to be timedelta) column to integers using

```
df['col'].astype(int, inplace = True)
```

Before calling the to_timedelta function. I really should have been doing

```
new_col = pd.to_numeric(df['col'])
```

and then calling to_timedelta on new_col. Maybe someone can shed light on why this would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default unit of `to_timedelta` are 'ns', please refer to the documentation or the function prototype:

```
def to_timedelta(arg, unit='ns', box=True, errors='raise', coerce=None):
```

So you just generated 1 to 5 naoseconds deltas, and the display doesn't go that deep.

It's likely you're picking the wrong unit, pass unit='something useful for you' to the function.

**Edit to explain more OP's comments**

By using the proper unit, you get what you expect:

```
pd.to_timedelta(my_series, unit='D')
Out[415]: 
0   1 days
1   2 days
2   3 days
3   4 days
4   5 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Still the type of the objects in that series are `timedelta[ns]` that is the internal representation of the object. ns in brackets is there to remind you that timedelta object has a precision scale down to the nanosecond.

If I take the raw internal value of the first element, I find nanoseconds:

```
pd.to_timedelta(my_series, unit='D')[0].delta
Out[425]: 86400000000000
```

Comment: This is indeed the case, the minimum value would be 1000 in order for timedelta to register this

Comment: @EdChum: well, "display", not "register" -- they're still _there_, in `pd.to_timedelta(my_series).dt.nanoseconds`. :-)

Comment: @DSM ah yes that's true I was just looking at the output without thinking about the timedelta attributes

Comment: Hmm actually I'm using unit = 'D' but the returned values say dtype: timedelta64[ns].

Comment: @EdChum added explanations in answer